# How do I get to the top bolt on the starter of my 1997 Saturn SL1?

Tags: starter, saturn, sl1

I went to replace the starter on my car, and I can't for the life of me reach that top bolt. I removed the bottom one just fine, but I've spent maybe 2 hours trying to find the top one and I just can't. It's totally blind.

How do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need about an 8" or 10" extension. Use the same 13mm socket as the bottom one. You'll also have to work blind, but it is (I believe) exactly opposite of the bottom one. Put the socket/extension up on the top side of the starter and find the bolt. It shouldn't be too difficult. Also, make sure all of your power is disconnected before you do it. [Here is a video showing you what you need](https://youtu.be/b0F7-A4J_3s?t=3m42s) ... I've queued it up to the spot where he's showing you what you'll need. It appears to be more difficult than it really is.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I tried watching that and it seems so much easier. I've done exactly what he says, go by feel but I just can't find the bolt. I don't know if there's anything you can tell me other than keep trying. I've been trying for almost 2 hours, and I just can't find where it is.

Comment: I've tried tons of different extensions, I've tried feeling by hand (I can't reach)...

Comment: First of all ... take a ***DEEP*** breath. Do like he said, put your hand up on the (as in Ducati's picture) left side of the start (around the nose cone) and find the bolt. Then guide the extension to the bolt from the other side. Use an extension which puts the ratchet just beyond the starter. You can see the length of this from the bottom side. The bolt, as I said, is exactly opposite of the bottom one.

Comment: @avid19  Perhaps try putting a larger socket on it to just fish around to see if you cahn get the location nailed.  Then put on the smaller socket once you've nailed the location.  ALSO...Are you sure the bolt is the same size?  I've seen a couple of starters that had different sized bolts.  Rare but possible.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - Yah, they both have 13mm heads on them.

Comment: @avid19 - ALSO!! Make sure you haven't swapped out sockets accidentally. Double check you have the 13mm on there, lol. Stranger things have happened.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thank you. I'll try these things tomorrow when it's light out. :) I'll try feeling from the left, if I can. There was a lot of stuff in the way.

Comment: @Paulster2   I've done that...

Comment: @avid19 - Please comment up in [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) (our chatroom) if you are still having issues. Someone can probably help you through it. I know it sux!